# How to calculate the enthalpy of formation?

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp

I am [following this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0966979509000892) to calculate the formation enthalpy of MgCu$_2$, in which the formation enthalpy is defined as follows:

[image]

where $E$(Mg$_x$X$_y$) is the total energy of the compound, and $E$(Mg) and $E$(X) are the total energies of pure elements in their stable structures. Since the influence of pressure on the condensed phases is ignored and the energies are calculated at $0$ K without any entropic contributions, the energy of formation is taken to be the enthalpy of formation.

Based on this, I calculated the formation enthalpy of MgCu$_2$. The calculation flow is shown below:

- The ground state energy for [the conventional cell of bulk MgCu$_2$](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-1038/) with Fd$\bar{3}$m space group:

  $E$(MgCu2)=-.75231981E+02 (eV)
- The ground state energy for the conventional cell of bulk Mg with P6$_3$/mmc space group:

  $E$(Mg)=-.30124735E+01 (eV)
- The ground state energy for the conventional cell of bulk Cu with Fm$_3$m space group:

  $E$(Cu)=-.14921761E+02 (eV)

Then the enthalpy of formation is estimated as:

$\Delta E_f$=$E$(MgCu2) - $\dfrac{1}{3}$ $E$(Mg) - $\dfrac{2}{3}$ $E$ (Cu) = -64.2799825 (eV)

In the reference paper, the unit kJ/mol is utilized. Due to [1eV=96 kJ/mol](http://www.colby.edu/chemistry/PChem/Hartree.html), then the enthalpy of formation in kJ/mol is:

$\Delta E_f$ = -64.2799825 (eV) = -6170.87832 (kJ/mol)

which is very different from the result of the reference paper:
[image]

What I am missing?

PS: the lattice constants for all structures are kept the same and all results are also calculated by VASP package with consistent parameters.

Comment: I gave +1 much earlier. The helpfulness of these links will vary, but I figured I'd add them before I forget: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/691/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3883/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/372/5, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1025/5 (see the links in the answer by Geoff Hutchison)

Answer (score 6):

I haven't been able to resolve everything, but here are some thoughts.

First, the form of Equation (1) assumes the energies are given on a per atom basis.

Second, try comparing the Materials Project energies against your energies. For example, with 24-, 2-, and 4-atom cells for MgCu2, Mg, and Cu, respectively:

- MgCu2:  [-3.3975](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-1038/#calculation-summary) **vs.** -3.1347 [= -75.231981 / 24] eV/atom;
- Mg:        [-1.5908](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-153/#calculation-summary) **vs.** -1.5062 [= -3.0124735 / 2] eV/atom;
- Cu:        [-4.0992](https://materialsproject.org/materials/mp-30/#calculation-summary) **vs.** -3.7304 [= -14.921761 / 4] eV/atom.

All three agree reasonably well.

Finally, note that inserting the Materials Project energies into Equation (1) yields -0.134 eV/atom, matching the Materials Project formation energy given for MgCu2. Doing the same for your energies yields -0.146 eV/atom. *However*, these values convert to -12.9 kJ/mol-atoms and -14.0 kJ/mol-atoms, respectively, which makes me a little skeptical of the -4.75 kJ/mol-atoms given in the paper.

Comment: For MgCu2, a conventional cell with 24 atoms has been utilized. My results are also consistent with the Materials Project.

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer using that info.